# PJAX: Facebook like box

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like, pjax

I have some problem in PJAX. When I navigating through pages using PJAX, facebook like box is not initialize. How do I initialize it? But when I refresh the page it's working fine. I'm using HTML5 version of Facebook like box plugin. Any idea?

If you need more info let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Solution is very simple. Don't use `HTML5` version. Use `iframe` version instead.